# Array of objects inside Async Storage - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to save an array of objects in Async storage that will be rendered as a list. Users will be able to add new items to the array and update and delete each.

At present, when saving the data, I find my array of objects only ever contains 1 object and each time I add a new one, the previous is overwritten.

Perhaps this is to do with the key used create each item, but I'm not sure how to auto-generate a unique key when working with Async?

Subsequently, when setting async to state, I only have 1 item to loop through when rendering the list.

**List.js**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

onLoad = async () => {
  try {
    const data = [];
    const item = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@foods');
    const d = JSON.parse(item);
    const { title } = d;
    data.push({ title });
  this.setState({ data });
console.log(this.state);
  } catch (error) {
    alert('Error', 'There was an error while loading the data');
  }
}

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
        />
        </View>
       );
     }
```

**AddItem.js** title (in state) is set from user input

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: ''
    };
  }

saveData = () => {
  const { title } = this.state;

  const data = {
    title
  };

  AsyncStorage.setItem('@foods', JSON.stringify(data));
  alert('save success');
}
```

My array of objects should look like this:

```
  const list = [
  {
    title,
    description,
    servingSize,
    servingNum
  },
  {
    title,
    description,
    servingSize,
    servingNum
  }
.....etc
]
```

Comment: Did you try Promise.all ?? It is the easiest way to do

Comment: @RaajNadar where would I include that?

Comment: Wait I will give you an example!

Comment: So do you know how many items are inserted in array or the setting as well as getting both are dynamic??

Comment: @RaajNadar yes both will be dynamic, the user should be able to create, update and delete as many items as they like (I would like to limit it for performance reasons in the future)

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are try is completely wrong try this method!

Getting multiple data from AsyncStorage

```
async loadData() {
   try {
       await Promise.all([AsyncStorage.getItem('data1'), AsyncStorage.getItem('data2')]).then((data) => {
          if ( data[0] != null && data[1] != null ) {
              someVar1 = data[0]; // First data from 1st promise
              someVar2 = data[1]; // Second data from 2nd promise
          }
       });
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Just saw you want to set data in AsynStorage as well

```
loadData() {
   AsyncStorage.multiSet([['data1', someVar.toString()], ['data2', someVar2.toString()]], (data) => {
       if(data) {
           alert("Something went wrong!");
       } else {
           // do something if the set was successful

        }
   });
}
```

Comment: how can I loop through the array without knowing how many items need to be returned?

Comment: Paste your JSON or array structure!

Comment: I've updated to show how the array of objects will look